# Kafka default consumer config for storage

Tags: apache-kafka

3.1 which is Kafka 0.11

When I set `offsets.storage=kafka` I get the following error: `The configuration 'offsets.storage' was supplied but isn't a known config.`

The client is 1.0.0

So I'm guessing the new default is kafka anyways?

Comment: offses.storage  is a connect config not consumer config

Comment: You mean kafka connect?

Comment: And why is it documented under "Old Consumer Configs"?